# Using xargs in case statement

Tags: shell, zsh, xargs

I want to pipe the output of a long command (which cannot be placed inside `$()`) to a case statement, so I'm using `xargs` like this

```
echo "this" | xargs -I{} case {} in; this) echo "is a test";; esac
```

which doesn't work, I get the error

```
zsh: parse error near `)'
```

whereas the following runs without a problem

```
case "this" in; this) echo "is a test";; esac
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`case...in...esac` are constructs in `sh`-like languages, so `xargs` (a separate command from the shell, not a shell construct) would need to invoke a shell for that:

```
echo this | xargs -I'{}' sh -c '
  case $1 in
    (this) echo "is a test";;
  esac' sh '{}'
```

In any case, you need to make sure the `{}` (which ends up being expanded by `xargs` to the contents of each line after quote and whitespace processing) is not passed in the *code* argument to `sh`, the inline script (or in the code argument to any interpreter, not only sh for that matters), as otherwise that would make it a code injection vulnerability.

Instead, here, the `{}` is passed as an argument to the inline script (which is retrieved in the script with `$1`) so there's no way it be interpreted as shell code.

If you wanted to run a `case` construct within your current (`zsh` here) shell on each line of the output of a command (which `xargs -I'{}'` by the way only does if those lines don't contain backslash, single quotes, double quotes and don't end in whitespaces), you could do:

```
while IFS= read <&3 -r line; do
  case $line in
    (this) ...;;
  esac 3<&-
done 3< <(a-command)
```

Or

```
for line (${(f)"$(a-command)"}) case $line in
  (this) ...;;
esac
```

(that one skips empty lines).

Comment: Why not `a-command | while IFS= read …`?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', to avoid stdin in the loop to be connected to the output of `a-command` as well (also improves compatibility with `bash` which would run the loop in a subshell with `a-command | while`). Using a separate fd would also be possible with `|` but more cumbersome.

Comment: What if I wanted to put that inside another `zsh` command like this (this gives an error): `zsh -c 'echo this | xargs -I'{}' zsh -c 'case $1 in; this) echo "is a test";; esac' sh {}'` (btw the command has to be a one-liner).

Comment: @noibe, Assuming that *one-liner command* itself is written in `sh` or `zsh` language, that would be `zsh -c 'echo this | xargs -I{} zsh -c '\''case $1 in; this) echo "is a test";; esac'\'' sh {}'` (but I struggle to see the point of that)

Comment: @EchoMike444, while the quotes around `'{}'` won't harm, there is no Bourne-like shell where they're necessary. See [GNU find and masking the {} for some shells - which?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/247786) for details.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas this was to be consistent with the first part of the command ... if you don't like my change please remove the quote after -I

Comment: @EchoMike444, no that's fine, I agree better to be consistent. Note that in `csh`, you do need the quotes in `-I'{}'` but not in `{}` alone, probably why I got into the habit of leaving only `{}` unquoted. In any case, in zsh, the quotes are not needed for either cases. There are several circumstances under which `{` or `}` need to be quoted though, so it's probably a good idea to get into the habit of quoting them.

Answer (score 0):

I’d have thought the issue is because a `case` statement is built up across multiple lines. You might have more success like this:

```
yourcommand | while read LINE ; do
  case "$LINE" in; this) echo "is a test";; esac
done
```

Comment: Note that the syntax to read a line is `IFS= read -r LINE`, not `read LINE`. Also note that `echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data (unless you're in `zsh` like the OP, and use `echo -E - $LINE`)